# Syntax for SQL query where the names start with 'n' different letters. Unique Names starting with multiple alphabets like b, e, g, h, t, etc

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to pull names in an Oracle SQL query where those names start with particular alphabets given in the input. For example, I need to pull unique names individually starting with some letters like a, c, f, etc.

Sample data should be starting with A, J, M

Output:

Albert
Alphonso
Ane

John
Jim
Jack

Matthew
Matt
Max

like this way.

What is the shortest syntax I can write to include multiple starting alphabets without using OR operators?

Comment: `b,e,g,h,t` or `a,c,f` or `a,j,m` ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `REGEXP_LIKE` here.  For example, to find all names starting in `A`, `J`, or `M` we can use:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM yourTable
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name, '^[AJM]', 'i');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUBSTR` (a simple string function which is faster than regular expressions) to find the first character and then use `IN`:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM   table_name
WHERE  SUBSTR(name, 1, 1) IN ('A', 'J', 'M')
```

If you have mixed case strings then you can use `UPPER` to normalise the cases:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM   table_name
WHERE  UPPER(SUBSTR(name, 1, 1)) IN ('A', 'J', 'M')
```

Comment: How to syntactically represent it using wildcards in SQL Oracle?

Comment: @HemanthKumarMuthyala What do you mean by "wildcards"?